# Writing a Function to Lapply Over Large List

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, lapply

Basically I have a large time series data frame over several days. I had written some code which works for one day at a time in the data frame but now I want to adapt it so that it runs for all days. For each day in my data frame there is a column containing the sunrise time for that day and one containing the sunset. I want to use these times to split each day into day hours and night hours. My sunrise sunset columns look like so and are different for each day:

```
Sunrise              Sunset
2010-01-19 08:55:12 2010-01-19 17:26:34
```

I have used split to divide the data frame by date to give a large list containing 10 elements (days)

```
# Splits data frame by date 
sepdays<- split(df, df$Date)

# Function to split each day into day and night hours
daynight <- function(){
rise <- as.character(df$Sunrise[1])
rise <- substr(rise, 12,19)
set <- as.character(df$Sunset[1])
set <- substr(set, 12,19)
day <- df[df$Time>rise & df$Time<set, ]
df.night1<-df[df$Time<rise,]
df.night2<-df[df$Time>set,]
night <- merge.data.frame(df.night1,df.night2, sort = TRUE, all.x = TRUE, all.y=TRUE)
return(table(day$Activity))
}

# Apply function over list of days
lapply(sepdays,daynight)
```

When I run lapply I get the unused arguments error:

> Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : unused argument (X[[1]])

I am also not sure if this is the best way to go about getting the specific sunrise/set times for each matching day. I realise that my function has no arguments but I am an R newbie so not really sure what I'm doing.

Here is what my data looks like.

```
Date       Time      Activity  Sunrise              Sunset
2010-01-19 23:58:00  1         2010-01-19 08:55:12  2010-01-19 17:26:34
2010-01-19 23:59:00  1         2010-01-19 08:55:12  2010-01-19 17:26:34
2010-01-19 00:00:00  0         2010-01-20 08:54:13  2010-01-20 17:28:11
2010-01-19 00:01:00  0         2010-01-20 08:54:13  2010-01-20 17:28:11
2010-01-20 00:02:00  1         2010-01-20 08:54:13  2010-01-20 17:28:11
2010-01-20 00:03:00  0         2010-01-20 08:54:13  2010-01-20 17:28:11
2010-01-20 00:04:00  1         2010-01-20 08:54:13  2010-01-20 17:28:11
```

I would like my ouput to contain for each date a table of activity e.g.:

```
2010-01-19
1  0
2  0

2010-01-20
1  0
2  3
```

Comment: You are trying to reinvent the wheel. Use R's datetime facilities and packages like plyr, dplyr or data.table. If you clearly state your ultimate goal and add example data (e.g., use `dput(head(df))`) to your question, some-one should be able to show you how to do this easily.

Comment: How are your example output tables related to the example input?

Comment: For each day, a table of activity values should be produced. I.e. the total number of 1s and the total number of 0s for each day.

Comment: The error message tells you that the function `daynight` needs to have an argument. `daynight <- function()` should probably be `daynight <- function(df)` instead.

Comment: I see two `1` and two `0` for the 2010-01-19. And where is the relation to Sunrise/Sunset times?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, because your question is pretty vague, but I think you could do this:

```
DF <- read.table(text="Date,       Time,      Activity,  Sunrise,              Sunset
2010-01-19, 23:58:00,  1,         2010-01-19 08:55:12,  2010-01-19 17:26:34
2010-01-19, 23:59:00,  1,         2010-01-19 08:55:12,  2010-01-19 17:26:34
2010-01-19, 00:00:00,  0,         2010-01-19 08:55:12,  2010-01-19 17:26:34
2010-01-19, 00:01:00,  0,         2010-01-19 08:55:12,  2010-01-19 17:26:34
2010-01-19, 09:01:00,  0,         2010-01-19 08:55:12,  2010-01-19 17:26:34
2010-01-20, 00:02:00,  1,         2010-01-20 08:54:13,  2010-01-20 17:28:11
2010-01-20, 00:03:00,  0,         2010-01-20 08:54:13,  2010-01-20 17:28:11
2010-01-20, 00:04:00,  1,         2010-01-20 08:54:13,  2010-01-20 17:28:11", header=TRUE, sep=",")

DF$datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(DF$Date, DF$Time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
DF$date <- as.Date(DF$datetime)
DF$Sunrise <- as.POSIXct(DF$Sunrise, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
DF$Sunset <- as.POSIXct(DF$Sunset, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")


DF$day <- (DF$datetime > DF$Sunrise) & (DF$datetime < DF$Sunset)

#        Date      Time Activity             Sunrise              Sunset            datetime   day       date
#1 2010-01-19  23:58:00        1 2010-01-19 08:55:12 2010-01-19 17:26:34 2010-01-19 23:58:00 FALSE 2010-01-19
#2 2010-01-19  23:59:00        1 2010-01-19 08:55:12 2010-01-19 17:26:34 2010-01-19 23:59:00 FALSE 2010-01-19
#3 2010-01-19  00:00:00        0 2010-01-19 08:55:12 2010-01-19 17:26:34 2010-01-19 00:00:00 FALSE 2010-01-19
#4 2010-01-19  00:01:00        0 2010-01-19 08:55:12 2010-01-19 17:26:34 2010-01-19 00:01:00 FALSE 2010-01-19
#5 2010-01-19  09:01:00        0 2010-01-19 08:55:12 2010-01-19 17:26:34 2010-01-19 09:01:00  TRUE 2010-01-19
#6 2010-01-20  00:02:00        1 2010-01-20 08:54:13 2010-01-20 17:28:11 2010-01-20 00:02:00 FALSE 2010-01-20
#7 2010-01-20  00:03:00        0 2010-01-20 08:54:13 2010-01-20 17:28:11 2010-01-20 00:03:00 FALSE 2010-01-20
#8 2010-01-20  00:04:00        1 2010-01-20 08:54:13 2010-01-20 17:28:11 2010-01-20 00:04:00 FALSE 2010-01-20

table(DF[,c("date", "Activity", "day")])

#, , day = FALSE
#
#            Activity
#date         0 1
#  2010-01-19 2 2
#  2010-01-20 1 2
#
#, , day = TRUE
#
#            Activity
#date         0 1
#  2010-01-19 1 0
#  2010-01-20 0 0
```

This is easier to read and much more efficient.